# Which function to use instead of pci_find_bus in esxi

Tags: unresolved-external, esxi

I am trying to compile a driver for **esxi** that originally run under linux.
When i try to load it vmkload i get the following error/warning

```
WARNING: Elf: 1508: Relocation of symbol <pci_find_bus> failed: Unresolved symbol
```

Because It is not defined in the vmklinux9 - Which one should i use instead?
I just saw it is under ifdef at:

```
vmkdrivers/src_9/include/linux/pci.h
vmkdrivers/src_9/vmklinux_9/linux/pci/search.c
```

Comment: Again, why the downvote? This question looks fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the interface by 
pci_get_device_all
got the physical address with
pci_resource_start
And finnaly got the virual adderss with ioreamp